# Xcode iPhone SDK - Keep NSInteger zero at beginning

Tags: ios, xcode, nsinteger

I want to keep the zero at the beginning of my `NSInteger`, but when i `NSLog` it, the zero is removed.

```
NSInteger myInteger = 05;
NSLog("%d", myInteger);
```

> log: 5

I get `5` instead of `05`. How can i keep the `0` at the beginning of the integer?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

NSInteger doesn't do "leading" zeros.  You're thinking about a number formatting thing.

If you just want to print out leading zeros via "`NSLog`", try something like:

```
NSLog( "%02d", myInteger);
```

Which instructs NSLog to have two digits and if it doesn't reach two digits, do a leading zero.

Take a look at the [printf format specifiers](http://personal.ee.surrey.ac.uk/Personal/R.Bowden/C/printf.html) (which NSLog tries to conform to) and you'll see how leading zeros are added there.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure, but I think it is a question of how you write your `"%d"` flag. So you cas use `NSLog(@"%03d", var);`.

It will print 005.

Answer (score 1):

This is how it works for strings:

INT

String(format:"%05.2f", 5.0) will output: 05.00

DOUBLE

String(format:"%02d", 5) will output: 05

Answer (score 0):

If you need it just for logging try it like this

```
NSLog(@"0%d" , 5) ;
```

or if you need to print it on the screen convert to string with format :

```
NSString *result = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"0%d" , yourInteger] ;
```

Comment: hard coding the zero will result in "05" yes, but if my `NSInteger` was 15 it would result in "015". Not preferred.